# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp

Tags: ios

using the following UIView class method on iPad to animate the swapping of different images inside a UIImageView:

```
        [UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                      duration:1.0 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                    animations:^{[imageView setImage:foregroundImage];} 
                    completion:nil];
```

However, the animation does not seem to be taking notice of the current interface orientation. In other words, "up" is always up relative to *Portrait* orientation. So, for example, if the device is in Landscape Left orientation, the page curls from left to right (rather than "up"). If I'm in Upside Down orientation, the page curls from top to bottom, etc.

Any idea how I can get it to curl "up" relative to the current interface orientation rather than only curling up relative to Portrait orientation?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. I've found a workaround but not sure why your code(the same approach I took) didn't work.

My walk-around is to create a wrapper(UIView) for all UI elements in the page to be purled. I've make the wrapper the only subview of the view controller's view and all other views subview of the wrapper. And modify the target to wrapper as below

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.wrapperView
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                animations:^{[imageView setImage:foregroundImage];} 
                completion:nil];
```

In your specific case, if you only need 'imageView' to be curled up, you can try set the target to imageView, namely

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
                animations:^{[imageView setImage:foregroundImage];} 
                completion:nil];
```

it worked in my project. So it seems if the animation target is the root view of VC, this problem will occur, otherwise the curling animation works find. Anyone knows why?

Comment: What a weird issue. Thanks for posting the solution. This seems like a bug.